# Need help trying to get the desired output from this input, get total_visits, most_visited_floor and resources_used

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Input:

| name | address | email | floor | resources |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Bangalore | A@gmail.com | 1 | CPU |
| A | Bangalore | A@gmail.com | 1 | CPU |
| A | Bangalore | A@gmail.com | 2 | DESKTOP |
| B | Bangalore | B1@gmail.com | 2 | DESKTOP |
| B | Bangalore | B1@gmail.com | 2 | DESKTOP |
| B | Bangalore | B1@gmail.com | 1 | MONITIOR |

Desired output:

| name | total visits | most visited floor | resources used |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 3 | 1 | CPU, ,DESKTOP |
| B | 3 | 2 | DESKTOP,MONITIOR |

so I came up with this code and approach using spark-sql but I am also ok if anyone is able to answer it in ms-sql or sql-server anything is fine

```
select name, concat_ws(',', collect_set(resources)) as resources_used, count(*) as total_visits 
from resources_table 
group by name
```

I am not able to compute the most_visited_floor column to get the desired output.

Appreciate the help

Comment: "DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc." https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I am surprised no upvote as the answer is also correct and on vs where makes no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is called in statistics [Mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mode_(statistics)).
Search for Mode + SQL and you'll find endless blogs and posts.

There are multiple ways to get the Mode.

Here is one option, assuming there is a single Mode value:

```
with 
t (name,address,email,floor,resources) as
(
    select  *
    from    values   ('A' ,'Bangalore' ,'A@gmail.com'  ,1  ,'CPU'     )
                    ,('A' ,'Bangalore' ,'A@gmail.com'  ,1  ,'CPU'     )
                    ,('A' ,'Bangalore' ,'A@gmail.com'  ,2  ,'DESKTOP' )
                    ,('B' ,'Bangalore' ,'B1@gmail.com' ,2  ,'DESKTOP' )
                    ,('B' ,'Bangalore' ,'B1@gmail.com' ,2  ,'DESKTOP' )
                    ,('B' ,'Bangalore' ,'B1@gmail.com' ,1  ,'MONITIOR')
),
t1 as
(
  select  * ,count(*) over (partition by name, floor) as count_name_floor
  from    t
)
select   name
        ,count(*)                              as total_visitsA
        ,max((count_name_floor,floor)).floor   as most_visited_floor
        ,concat_ws(',',collect_set(resources)) as resources_used
from     t1
group by name
```

| name | total_visits | most_visited_floor | resources_used |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| B | 3 | 2 | MONITIOR,DESKTOP |
| A | 3 | 1 | DESKTOP,CPU |

Here is another option assuming there might be multiple Mode values.
I added 2 rows to the input, to make it more interesting.

```
with 
t (name,address,email,floor,resources) as
(
    select  *
    from    values   ('A' ,'Bangalore' ,'A@gmail.com'  ,1  ,'CPU'     )
                    ,('A' ,'Bangalore' ,'A@gmail.com'  ,1  ,'CPU'     )
                    ,('A' ,'Bangalore' ,'A@gmail.com'  ,2  ,'DESKTOP' )
                    ,('B' ,'Bangalore' ,'B1@gmail.com' ,2  ,'DESKTOP' )
                    ,('B' ,'Bangalore' ,'B1@gmail.com' ,2  ,'DESKTOP' )
                    ,('B' ,'Bangalore' ,'B1@gmail.com' ,1  ,'MONITIOR')
                    ,('B' ,'Bangalore' ,'B1@gmail.com' ,1  ,'MONITIOR')
                    ,('B' ,'Bangalore' ,'B1@gmail.com' ,3  ,'MONITIOR')
),
t1 as
(
  select  * ,count(*) over (partition by name, floor) as count_name_floor
  from    t
),
t2 as
(
  select  * ,rank() over (partition by name order by count_name_floor desc) as rank_count_name_floor
  from    t1
)
select   name
        ,count(*)                                                                      as total_visitsA
        ,concat_ws(',',collect_set(case rank_count_name_floor when 1 then floor end))  as most_visited_floors
        ,concat_ws(',',collect_set(resources))                                         as resources_used
from     t2
group by name
```

| name | total_visitsA | most_visited_floors | resources_used |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 3 | 1 | DESKTOP,CPU |
| B | 5 | 1,2 | MONITIOR,DESKTOP |

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
val df = Seq( 
              ( "A", "Bangalore", "a*.com", 1, "cpu" ),
              ( "A", "Bangalore", "a*.com", 1, "cpu" ),
              ( "A", "Bangalore", "a*.com", 2, "desktop" ),
              ( "B", "Bangalore", "a*.com", 2, "desktop" ),
              ( "B", "Bangalore", "a*.com", 2, "desktop" ),
              ( "B", "Bangalore", "a*.com", 1, "monitor" ),
             ).toDF("name" ,"address", "email", "floor", "resource")

df.createOrReplaceTempView("R")

val res = spark.sql(""" 

                      select A.name, A.total_visits, B.floor, C.resources from (  
                        select R.name, count(*) as total_visits 
                          from R
                      group by R.name  ) A,
               
                        (
                        select Z.name, Z.floor, Z.most_visited
                          from (
                        select X.*, rank() over (partition by X.name order by X.most_visited desc) as RANK
                          from (
                                select R.name, R.floor, count(R.floor) as most_visited 
                                  from R
                              group by R.name, R.floor) X ) Z     
                        where Z.RANK = 1 ) B, 

                        (
                        select R.name, array_sort(collect_set(resource)) as resources 
                          from R
                      group by R.name ) C
                    where A.name = B.name and B.name = C.name
                         
                    """)
res.show(false)
```

It returns:

```
+----+------------+-----+------------------+
|name|total_visits|floor|resources         |
+----+------------+-----+------------------+
|A   |3           |1    |[cpu, desktop]    |
|B   |3           |2    |[desktop, monitor]|
+----+------------+-----+------------------+
```

Comment: `where A.name = B.name and B.name = C.name`?! Seriously?! ANSI/ISO JOIN was introduce on 1992, 30(!) years ago

Comment: Old fashioned bro…@DavidדודוMarkovitz

Comment: Since you are using Spark which was open sourced in 2010, it seems you have no problems to adopt to changes. There are good reasons to why a new Join syntax was introduced back then.

Comment: Each to his own. I am pretty good at sql as this site will partially show but i never took to ON and such. I write less sql these days but the result counts. @DavidדודוMarkovitz